# What is the format of Laravel Eloquent timestamps?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

In my applications I use two libraries - [Node.js](http://nodejs.org/) and [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) - which both interact with the same MySQL database tables to modify, insert and delete various data. Since my schema is created by Laravel migrations (which allow for `timestamps`), I wanted my Node.js application to also replicate the `updated_at` and `created_at` fields Eloquent uses. However, I realized I didn't know the format of the timestamps. So, the question was:

What is the format of Laravel's Eloquent timestamps?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Laravel's [Eloquent ORM](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent) actually uses [MySQL's `timestamp` data type](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/datetime.html) for formatting and storing the data. The format for these timestamps follows the following format, as specified by the MySQL documentation:

> MySQL retrieves and displays...values in 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS' format.

Also according to their docs:

> TIMESTAMP has a range of '1970-01-01 00:00:01' UTC to '2038-01-19 03:14:07' UTC.

In example, a date of around when this question was asked - October 12, 2014 (8:15 PM) would be formatted like `2014-10-12 21:15:34`. Recognize that single digit numbers have a zero digit in front of them, as the formatting specifies two digits for each value (except for years, which has four).