# Unknown column type "timestamp" requested. Any Doctrine type that you use has to be registered with \Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Type::addType(). Laravel 6

Tags: php, timestamp, laravel-6, laravel-migrations, dbal

I am using laravel 6 and i had the following migration code

```
 Schema::create('work_schedule_times', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->time('start_time');
            $table->time('end_time');
        });
```

now i have to make changes in my new migrations to update `time` from `timestamp`. I have following code

```
Schema::table('employee_work_schedules', function (Blueprint $table) {
            
            $table->timestamp('start_time')->change();
            $table->timestamp('end_time')->nullable()->change();
        });
    }
```

when i run the migration i am getting following error

```
 Unknown column type "timestamp" requested. Any Doctrine type that you use has to be registered with \Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Type::addType(). You can get a list of all the known types with \Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Type::getTypesMap(). If this error occurs during database introspection then you might have forgotten to register all database types for a Doctrine Type. Use AbstractPlatform#registerDoctrineTypeMapping() or have your custom types implement Type#getMappedDatabaseTypes(). If the type name is empty you might have a problem with the cache or forgot some mapping information.
```

Since laravel 9 is addressing this issue by giving following guidelines

```
If you plan to modify columns created using the timestamp method, you must also add the following configuration to your application's config/database.php configuration file:
use Illuminate\Database\DBAL\TimestampType;
 
'dbal' => [
    'types' => [
        'timestamp' => TimestampType::class,
    ],
],
```

since i am using laravel 6 and i am beginner i dont know how to fix this error since `start_time` must have timestamp datatype

Comment: I think you should read this:
[What is the format of Laravel Eloquent timestamps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26332418/what-is-the-format-of-laravel-eloquent-timestamps)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the format of Laravel Eloquent timestamps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26332418/what-is-the-format-of-laravel-eloquent-timestamps)